# Sorting row values and displaying the column order

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, data-analysis

I am trying to a data frame which is something like this

```
user_name   tag1   tag2   tag3   tag4
    user1    .65    .32    .91      0
    user2    .34    .44    .21    .56
    user3    .21      0      0    .19
```

I need to sort each row on the values of column and get the result columns with highest value and decreasing for each row, also need to remove columns having 0 value for particular user. . output should look like something this.

```
user_name       0      1      2     3
    user1    tag3   tag1   tag2  
    user2    tag4   tag2   tag1   tag3
    user3    tag1   tag4
```

or transpose of this will also work. I need to do this in python2.7. Thank you.

Comment: is this `pandas` if so add the tag

Comment: added @EdChum new to this site. any help on code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the `0` values with `NaN` then you can `apply` a `lambda` to mask the index:

```
In [28]:
df.replace(0,np.NaN, inplace=True)
def func(x):
    val = x.sort_values(ascending=False).index.to_series()
    mask = pd.isnull(x)
    val[mask] = ''
    return val.values
df.ix[:, 'tag1':] = df.ix[:, 'tag1':].apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
df

Out[28]:
  user_name  tag1  tag2  tag3  tag4
0     user1  tag3  tag1  tag2      
1     user2  tag4  tag2  tag1  tag3
2     user3  tag1  tag4
```

I use `NaN` here rather than comparing against `0` because comparing against float scalar values are problematic and may not work:

```
In [32]:
def func(x):
    val = x.sort_values(ascending=False).index.to_series()
    mask = val == 0
    val[mask] = ''
    return val.values
df.ix[:, 'tag1':] = df.ix[:, 'tag1':].apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
df

Out[32]:
  user_name  tag1  tag2  tag3  tag4
0     user1  tag3  tag1  tag2  tag4
1     user2  tag4  tag2  tag1  tag3
2     user3  tag1  tag4  tag3  tag2
```

I return a np array using `.values` because otherwise the Series  that would have been returned would align against the original column names, so no ordering would occur

Additionally I have to call `to_series` on the `Index` object as you've can't mutate an Index object with this line: `val[mask] = ''`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `list.sort()` function. If you enter all the tags of an user in a list and then sort the list, you should find the desired result

Comment: tags here shown are for example there are large no. of tags